# Restarting due to SPID stuck on RUNNING, KILLED/ROLLEDBACK status

Tags: sql-server, triggers, restart, lockup

I'm a new "accidental" DBA and I'm currently trying to resolve a lockup caused by a trigger I created on a production database supporting a front end application.

I created a trigger, and then I decided I'd be best off creating a job to do the work instead, so tried to delete the trigger in object explorer. The delete failed with the message:

```
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. 

Lock request time out period exceeded.
```

I then tried to manually drop it and it failed at 0%, 0s left to go. I checked for the longest running transaction and then tried to kill the process in activity monitor. Since then the process has been stuck on "Task State:RUNNING and Command:KILLED/ROLLBACK". After some googling it sounds like I have two options.

Option 1: Restart DTC on the SQL server.... didn't work, still stuck.
Option 2: Restart the SQL service. Uh-oh.

This is the first time I've ever had to do anything like this and I'm pretty nervous being the only SQL guy in the office. Please can anyone let me know what the potential implications of restarting the service are, in terms of data loss and impact to front end users? Am I better off waiting to restart after business hours?

Thanks, and apologies if I've asked this question badly, first time for everything.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait. It's rolling back and has to finish the rollback. Don't restart SQL, that will just result in the rollback continuing after the restart, possibly with the database offline.

If this is a production system and you do bounce the database, all users of your user interface will get weird and wonderful errors. Unless your application can handle it, your users will have a bad experience and then you will start getting phone calls from the boss....

As a side note, check for locking\blocking processes. The message in the question "Lock request time out period exceeded. " seems to suggest there is locking/blocking happening.

Comment: Thanks Sarin. I've been looking at the blocking chain with who2 and the stuck SPID is at the head. I have a feeling that the trigger I created must have been bad (worked in test) and was stuck in a loop or long running operation when I tried to kill it.... Poor form from me.

Comment: You will get a better response if you ask this question in the Database Administrators stack site.